# NancyFx устанавливается с ошибкой,как устранить?

Tags: c#

Изучаю фреймворк Nancy, как альтернативу тяжелому ASP.net. Использую ASP.netcore. Делаю пустой проект, через нугет ставлю Nancy и виду такую картину. Предупреждение в виде  восклицательного знака. И предупреждение. 
Предупреждение  NU1701  Пакет "Nancy 1.4.5" был восстановлен с помощью ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1", а не целевой платформы проекта ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0". Этот пакет может быть не полностью совместим с вашим проектом.    WebApplication9 C:***\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WebApplication9\WebApplication9\WebApplication9.csproj
Использую VS 2017 Enterptise. Читаю документацию третий день,не работает.

Comment: Вам же прямо сказано: целевая платформа пакета - `.NET Framework 4.6.1+`. Вы же используете даже не `.NET Framеwork`, а `.NET Core 2.0`. Либо используйте `ASP.NET`, либо найдите версию пакета для Core (если она вообще существует)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Спасибо за ответ, а я никак не могу понять в чем дело, но у меня сказано использовать netcore и nancy

Comment: посмотрите [здесь](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2863), тут как раз обсуждают запуск под `.NET Core 2.0`. Как я понял, Вы читаете что-то старенькое, ориентированное на `.NET Core 1.1` (когда в ходу уже 2.1))

Comment: @Kir_Antipov )) да я уже перекомпоновал ее и под  core 1.1 и вчера скачал с майкрософта последнюю SdK, спасибо за ссылку, буду разбираться.

Comment: Таки удачи Вам)